# Multiple Authentication Models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication

I am working on a project where I need to have 3 types of Users.

1. Staff (for admin,superadmin like stuff)
2. Dealers
3. Customers

i have created 3 models using **AbstractBaseUser** class . I also created separate model managers for each .

models.py

```
class Staff(AbstractBaseUser):
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
# fields 

class Customer(common_modelfields):
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
# customer specific fields 

class Dealer(common_modelfields):
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
# dealer specific fields
```

after getting through this [Django Multiple Auth Models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47250398/19381810)

i made a custom authentication backend **authentication.py** as follows:

```
from .models import Staff,Customer,Dealer

var_model = ""
class authentication_models_backends(object):
def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
    global var_model
    if "admin" in request.path:
        var_model = Staff
    elif "customer" in request.path:
        var_model = Customer
    elif "dealer" in request.path:
        var_model = Dealer
    else :
        return "no_model_found"
   # authenticate user based on request object
    try:
        validated_email = email.lower()
        if var_model.objects.filter(email=validated_email).exists():
            user = var_model.objects.get(email = validated_email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return "invalid password"
        else:
            return "email not found"
    except var_model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
        
def get_user(self, user_id):
    # logic to get user
    try:
        return var_model.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except var_model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Staff'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['account.authentication.authentication_models_backends',]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',#(user not found error)
)}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
'AUDIENCE': None,
'ISSUER': None,
'JWK_URL': None,
'LEEWAY': 0,

'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',}
```

api **URL** which i hit with **GET** request by postman

```
path("customerprofileview/", customer_profile_view.as_view(),name='customerprofileview'),
path("dealerprofileview/", dealer_profile_view.as_view(),name='dealerprofileview'),
```

here is a **View** with **Serializer** :

```
class customer_profile_view(APIView):
renderer_classes = [apirenderer]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
def get(self,request,format=None):
    try:
        serializer_object = customer_profile_serializer(request.user)
    except:
        pass
    return Response(serializer_object.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class customer_profile_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Customer
    fields = ['id','full_name','email','unique_id','full_number','house_no','locality','state']
```

however django is looking only for the model mentioned in **AUTH_USER_MODEL**,if user is not an instance of AUTH_USER_MODEL's value then it throws **user_not_found error** . Hence, Not searching in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

i am assigning token to user on login via **simple-jwt RefreshToken method** and i want to get the logged in user details from models according to request - as you can see the logic in authentication.py .

i got stuck at this point . please help me to proceed further

**EDIT** : i forgot to mention earlier that **i am not using django.contrib.auth's authenticate method** to authenticate users.

Comment: You know in terms of using Django's auth and `AbstractUser` you have `groups` built in through `auth.group`...this sounds like  perfect time to use it. Also, why do you still have Django's default auth backend added if you created your own? Django will first try to authenticate using `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`, which is the default backend of Django. If that fails, then it moves on to the next backend, which is your custom one

Comment: if you have multiple types of User then I think so you have to use Proxy model it will easy to use and understandable you can learn about from here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0hdXr2MOEA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need three models for user authentication. You can use one model with roles defined.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
...
...
...
CUSTOMER = 'customer'
STAFF = 'staff'
DEALER = 'dealer'
USER_ROLES= [
        (CUSTOMER, 'customer'),
        (STAFF, 'staff'),
        (DEALER, 'dealer'),
    ]
user = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_ROLES, default="your-default")
```